# Can I bulk move structure entries?

Tags: structure, update, bulk

I currently have hundreds of entries listed in structure 2 levels deep like this:

-Category
--Sub Category [X10]
---Item [x10]

(These are not expression engine categories but structure pages with sub pages)

I want to move all of the items up one level and remove the sub category so it will look like this.

-Category
--Item [x100]

Is there an easy way to bulk update these entries or will I have to do it manually?

Thanks,

Colin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid you will have to do it manually without writing some sort of custom script.